# Drag and drop feature in android studio doesn't allow to to place where I want to

Tags: xml, android-studio

I can't drag and drop things where i want in the andriod studio design editor.

Al the items just go into the top row.

I can drag and drop in other projects I imported for my class, but when i make my own they can't be moved.

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#E1BD88"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextPhone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="phone"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="42dp"`your text`
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="170dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="227dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="200dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOfxz.png)